# Why do we need to hash both the message and the $h$ value in ElGamal signature?

Tags: elgamal-signature, forgery

The professor left us a question on ElGamal signatures:

> Given the hash function $H$ and message $M$, choose a random $r$ and compute $h=g^r$ and $H(M||h)$. Show that, if $H(M)$ is used instead of $H(M||h)$, the signature can be existentially forged.

I am struggling with the problem, and I think that maybe we can get one known message signed twice with different $(M, c_1, h_1)$ and $(M, c_2, h_2)$, and then use that to sign some other messages $M'$, but I have no idea how to proceed. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: I tried to clean up your question a bit, but there were some places where I wasn't really sure what you meant. Could you please check that I didn't introduce any mistakes, and maybe try to clarify your question further.

Comment: It would useful to clarify how the question relates to the [ElGamal signature scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a complete answer because an adversary needs control on the random choice of a signing algorithm.

1. First let me define ElGamal signature to not get lost in notation.
   $x \in N$ is the secret key.
   $p$ is a prime, it defines $Z_p^*$.
   $g$ is a generator of $Z_p^*$.
   $y=g^x$ and the public key is $(p, g, g^x)$.
   Then $k$ is picked at random from $0<k<p-1$,
   $r = g^k \bmod p$, $s = (H(m) - xr)k^{-1} \bmod (p-1)$ and the signature is 
   $(r,s)$.
2. Suppose we know two signatures of the message $m$ for different $k$-s:
   $\sigma_1 = (g^{k_1} \bmod p, (H(m) - xr)k_1^{-1} \bmod (p-1)) = (r_1, s_1)$ and 
   $\sigma_2 = (g^{k_2} \bmod p, (H(m) - xr)k_2^{-1} \bmod (p-1)) = (r_2, s_2)$.

Let $\sigma_3=(r_1r_2 \bmod p, s_1 + s_2 \bmod (p-1))$.

3. Verification of $\sigma_3$ leads us to an equation $(k_1+k_2)(k_1^{-1}+k_2^{-1})\equiv 1 \bmod (p-1)$. If an attacker can choose $k_1, k_2$, then he can probably find proper $p$ and $k_1, k_2$. Otherwise - still a problem.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Bleichenbacher has described such kind of attacks in his article 
[Generating ElGamal signatures without knowing the secret key.](ftp://ftp.inf.ethz.ch/pub/crypto/publications/Bleich96.pdf) (PDF)

He noticed that if verifier would accept signatures where $r$ is larger than $p$ then any signature $(r,s)$ on $H(M)$ could be used to generate a signature $(r2, s2)$ on arbitrary hash value $H(M2)$.

For that attacker should calculate $u=H(M2)H(M)^{-1} \bmod (p-1)$. 
This implies $g^{H(M2)}=g^{uH(M)}=y^{ru}r^{su}$. $s2$ could be setting as $s2=su\bmod (p-1)$ and $r2$ could be computing by using Chinese Remainder Theorem for two equations $r2=ru\bmod (p-1)$ and $r2=r\bmod p$.